# Changing background color for MANY strings based on whether they include a certain word?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to check if a bunch of strings have a certain word. If an individual member of that class has the specified word ('unlikely'), then I change background color to green. If an individual member of that class doesn't, then background color is red. So the end result will be a bunch of members of the class with a green background and others with a red background.

My code is not working.

Here's what I've tried.

```
function colorCoding() {
    var str = document.getElementsByClassName("colorString").innerHTML;
    var n = str.includes("unlikely");
    if (n==true) {
      document.getElementById("colorString").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("colorString").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

The background color is not changing at all.

I've tried doing it for each individual ID—and it worked—but that would take me forever to go through each member of the class and create a function based on their individual ID. Is there any way to do it with the class? Or without the class, but still using one function for the entire set?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try to use `document.querySelector` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `document.getElementsByClassName("colorString").innerHTML`. You must include the index. It should be like `document.getElementsByClassName("colorString")[0].innerHTML`.

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements with that class name.

For loop:-

```
 var i;

 var str = document.getElementsByClassName("colorString");
 for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    if(str[i].innerHTML.includes("unlikely")) { 
      str[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
  str[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

 }
```

Comment: But then won't I have to do that for each and every member of the class? Is there any way to check if a set of strings contain a certain word?

Comment: You can use a `for` loop

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh, I see. I'm not very familiar with for loops. I'll look into this myself, and am very thankful, but can you point me in the direction of how I would write that code?

Comment: Updated the solution. w3schols and Mozilla developers have some great resources for learning.

Comment: Thanks a ton, this is very helpful.

Comment: @user1580462 There is a small edit `for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++)`. I have removed `=` from `i <= str.length;`